# htaccess RewriteRule first parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to have SEO friendly URLs and read some tutorials about htaccess, but I can't get the RewriteRule to work.

My original URL (id is dynamic):

```
www.mydomain.com/view-movie/?id=1
```

I use a clean_url() function to get this format:

```
www.mydomain.com/view-movie/id/seo-friendly-title/
```

example:

```
www.mydomain.com/view-movie/1/this-is-my-title/
```

This is my try (the last line is my try, the other stuff is default wordpress):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^view-movie/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ view-movie/?id=$1
</IfModule>
```

Comment: you have it backwards.
RewriteRule ^/view-movie/?id=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) /view-movie/$1 [L]

Comment: I get a 404 error with that rule.

Comment: I don't know why it didn't work, but I used wordpress custom rewrite_rule to make it work: https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule